# Combination of entries from N lists

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have N lists [the size of each list might vary] in python. The value of N itself might vary too.

Let us consider an example where the number of lists are 3 [for simplicity, each list has size 2]:

```
[A, B], [C, D], [E, F]
```

Now what I am expecting is something like this:

```
ACE, ADE, ACF, ADF, BCE, BDE, BCF, BDF
```

A combination of each entry from all the lists [we will avoid combining entries from the same list].

What would be the most efficient way of solving this problem? [I am unsure if a similar problem is available online, as I wasn't able to find one].

Comment: check out itertools, theres cool stuff in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.product` does exactly what you need:

```
##separate lists
ls1 = ['A','B']
ls2 = ['C','D']
ls3 = ['E','F','G']
out = list(product(ls1,ls2,ls3))

##or, list of lists, using the * operator
ls = [['A','B'],['C','D'],['E','F','G']]
out = list(product(*ls))

##in both cases
print(out)
[('A', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'G'), ('A', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'D', 'F'), ('A', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'C', 'E'), ('B', 'C', 'F'), ('B', 'C', 'G'), ('B', 'D', 'E'), ('B', 'D', 'F'), ('B', 'D', 'G')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. And data around the efficiency?

Comment: Standard library functions are highly optimized, so you can assume using `product` is your best option. The costly part of my answer above is casting the returned `iterator` to a `list`, which may be unnecessary if you just need to loop over the results. But even with the casting it will be much faster than, for instance, using nested `for` loops or a `list comprehension` with a fixed number of sublists

Answer (score 1):

Running this code:

```py
from itertools import product
from functools import reduce

def combine_words(list1, list2):
    word_pairs = product(list1, list2)
    combined_words = []
    for pair in word_pairs:
        combined_words.append("".join(pair))
    return combined_words

reduce(combine_words, [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], ["E", "F"]])
```

Will return the following result:

```
['ACE', 'ACF', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'BCE', 'BCF', 'BDE', 'BDF']
```

It works regardless of the number of words in each list, or regardless of the number of lists inside the total list.

Comment: `itertools.product` can be applied to a variable number of lists directly, for instance unpacking a list of lists: `ll = [list1, list2, list3]; result = product(*ll)`.

Comment: Also, I think it would be more intuitive to only use `''.join` once, after `reduce`. But that only works if the tuple are collapsed :( `ll = [list1, list2, list3]; result = [''.join(collapse(p)) for p in reduce(product, ll)]` where `collapse` is from `more_itertools` and collapses a nested structure: [more_itertools.collapse](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collapse)

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the comments. You're absolutely right. Should I edit my answer to simplify it with your feedback? Or do I just leave it as is?

Comment: Thank you for your time. And data around the efficiency?

Comment: @scr it's a free world

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a product rather than a combination problem.

Because Python strings can be iterated over as if they were a list of characters this leads to several ways in which the input could be stated. (I like the third way as it can be less typing if spaces are not in any of the "words").

### Code

```py
from itertools import product
from typing import List, Union

def word_product(list_of_lists: Union[List[List[str]], List[str]]) -> str:
    return ', '.join(''.join(values) for values in product(*list_of_lists))

example1 = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]
print(word_product(example1))

example2 = ["AB", "CD", "EF"]
print(word_product(example2))

example3 = "AB CD EF".split()
print(word_product(example3))
```

#### Output

It is the same line for each of the equivalent example inputs:

```
ACE, ACF, ADE, ADF, BCE, BCF, BDE, BDF
ACE, ACF, ADE, ADF, BCE, BCF, BDE, BDF
ACE, ACF, ADE, ADF, BCE, BCF, BDE, BDF
```

Comment: *"It turns out to be a product rather than a combination problem."* In the absence of more explanation, this sentence is not very meaningful. The specific vocabulary used in module `itertools` to distinguish between "permutations", "combinations with replacement", "combinations without replacement" and "Cartesian product" is relatively standard in a small subfield of programming, but not at all standard in the broader field of computer science. In particular, it kinds of conflicts with the way mathematics uses these terms, and the way most people use the term "combinations".

Comment: *Context*: [python] is stated in the question this is an answer for.

Comment: Note that despite my previous comment, I agree that finding the most specific and relevant keywords is extremely helpful especially when searching through library documentation or through stackoverflow. But I think this sentence *""It turns out to be a product rather than a combination problem.""* really needs further explanation, or it doesn't make sense. At the very least you could say "Cartesian product" instead of just "product" and link to the itertools documentation.

Comment: *" Context: [python] is stated in the question this is an answer for. "* Yes? How does the tag  [python] will help the OP or future readers make sense of the distinction you make between "product problem" and "combination problem"?

Comment: It asks for a Python solution. I expect people to *read* and know that. product is a standard library function. It's not too much to expect a lot of Python programmers to know of it, and even more to know how to search for its definition. It's not golfing.

Comment: Wait, are you @Stef asking me to cater for those readers that do not know Python?

Comment: Thank you for your time. And data around the efficiency?

Comment: Were is it deficient? What tests have you done?